# How to split inputStream from Serial port?

Tags: java, serial-port, inputstream

I'm reading the data from a serial port using InputStream.

One part of the stream I need to convert to String, and the other one to binary data.

I already have two methods, and each one does what is needed, but I need to send the data from the serial port twice for both methods to work

My question is if I can somehow split the stream so I can get all of the data to two methods in one send from the serial port?

```
private static void readingBytesSN(SerialPort comPort) {

    comPort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
        @Override
        public int getListeningEvents() {
            return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE;
        }

        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent serialPortEvent) {

            InputStream in;

            String startSn2 = "110000010011010001101100100011011000100011010000111000010001010";
            String newLine2 = "01100000110110010001101100010001101000011100001000101";

            String startSn = "27434877273598525669";
            String newLine = "12273598525669";
            String endOfSn = "12694954545053565052661310";
            String endOfData = "1227513232131032131032131032131032131027109275132";


            String s1 = "";
            String s2 = "";

            if (serialPortEvent.getEventType() != SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE) {
                return;
            }

            int x = 0;
            try {

                in = comPort.getInputStream();

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);

                List<String> line = new ArrayList<>();

                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    line.add(sc.next());
                    if (line.contains("\u001Bm\u001B3")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                while (((x = in.read()) != 109)) {
                    s1 += String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(x & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
                }
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] snArray = s1.split(startSn2);
            

            for (int i = 1; i < snArray.length; i++) {

                BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
                Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
                Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 2);
                g2d.setFont(font);
                int height = g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight();
                g2d.dispose();

                img = new BufferedImage(384, 40, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                g2d = img.createGraphics();

                g2d.setFont(font);
                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                int fontSize = 1;

                for (String line : snArray[i].split(newLine2)) {

                    g2d.drawString(line, 0, height);
                    height += fontSize;
                    //System.out.println("Serial number: " + line);
                }
                //g2d.dispose();
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("images\\Text" + i + ".png"));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                g2d.dispose();

                String result = null;
                try {
                    result = SerialOcr("images\\Text" + i + ".png");
                } catch (TesseractException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(result);

            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please post your code so far

Comment: This could be tricky. I don't think it's necessarily a valid approach to read 'lines' with a `Scanner` then simply continue reading the underlying input stream. I think you'd better dump the entire contents of the input stream to a file (don't try to read `String` - just bytes) and then post a link to it for me to advise properly. You can use `try (InputStream in = comPort().getInputStream()) {
            in.transferTo(Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("data.bin")));
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
`

Comment: Here is the file that I got with your code [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0b8bcb99efb1f4a77e00eabb4f7aaca520221230192656/8f178e)

Comment: Well done. I'll take a look

Comment: At first glance, no code after you'd finished reading lines is going to run as `"\u001Bm\u001B3"` terminates the input. By "input" (and until further notice) I mean the contents of the file you gave me. It's probably going to be a good idea if you isolate the parsing into a separate method, with a prototype such as `private void parse(InputStream in)`. That will make it easier, while testing, to supply the input from a file instead of the serial port

Comment: The problem is that when I press "Print" on the device, it sends the data and the scanner does its job to collect the text data. The other part of the code `while (((x = in.read()) != 109))`  does the job of getting the pictures and all of this works perfectly, except I need to press "Print" two times for all of the code to execute.

Comment: Ok. You should have pressed it twice to produce the file in that case. With no programming involved, do you have to press it twice then?

Comment: When I press "Print" I get all the data that I need, but it gets used up by Scanner, and then I need to press it again to use it in the while loop. I always get the same current data when printing. I posted an answer on how I managed to get it to work, maybe you have some better suggestion?

Comment: What is this hardware - some meteorological device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I repeated the input stream using this code.

```
InputStream bufferdInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(myInputStream);

bufferdInputStream.mark(some_value);
//do the first method
bufferdInputStream.reset();
//do the second method
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined just to read the whole lot into `byte[]` then you can process that

Comment: Currently, I'm using it with the code above, but I will give it a try with your suggestion also. Now I'm trying to show the progress bar when receiving the data from the device, but I'm having problems with showing the correct progress. But I guess I'll make another question about this. Thanks a lot again.